# Cocoa HTTP PUT with content-range

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to use an NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest combination to send a PUT request to a server with a Content-Range header? By that I mean I want to resume an upload to the server which can accept a byte range in the request to resume the upload.

I see you can set an NSInputStream as the request body so I figured that I could subclass that and override the the open/seek functions and set the request header but it seems to call on undocumented selectors and break the implementation.

I'm sure I could do this with CFNetwork but it just seems like there must be a way to do it with the higher level APIs.

Any ideas on where to start?

EDIT:

To answer my own question, this is indeed possible after reading a blog [http://bjhomer.blogspot.com/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html] which details the undocumented callbacks which relate to CFStream. Once those are implemented I can call the following in the `open` callback to skip ahead:

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)parentStream, kCFStreamPropertyFileCurrentOffset, (CFNumberRef)[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:streamOffset]);
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: Note: There's no need to drop down to the CF-level: `-[NSStream setPorperty:forKey:]` allows you to do that just fine! The key to use there is `NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey` which is in OS X since 10.3 and on iOS since 2.0. (See the ["Constants"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001981-SW24) section in the `NSStream` docs)

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed! If you add this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I posted in my comment, you can facilitate what you want without dropping down to the CoreFoundation level:

As `NSInputStream` inherits `NSStream`, it is possible to prepare the stream as follows:

```
NSNumber *streamOffset = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:lastOffset];

[inputStream setProperty:streamOffset forKey: NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey];
```

(Assuming `lastOffset` is an `NSUInteger` representation of your last file offset in bytes and `inputStream` is the stream you want to set as the request's `HTTPBodyStream`.)

Answer (score 6):

I think the server needs to supports put method combines with range but this will be the way to do it with high level Objective-C API

```
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        NSString *range = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%lld-%lld",bytesUploaded,uploadSize];
        [urlRequest addValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
        self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, the above is fundamentally correct however the issue is with the input stream. The documentation says that "The entire contents of the stream will be sent as the body, as in an HTTP POST request. The inputStream should be unopened and the receiver will take over as the stream’s delegate." which is not desirable, I need the stream to seek to the correct offset and send from there.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to do fancy work with HTTP, I typically recommend [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's solid stuff that simplifies a lot of more complicated HTTP problems. It's not really needed for setting a simple header, but if you're starting to build something more complex, it can be nice to move over to ASI sooner rather than later.

With an `NSMutableURLRequest`, you can set any header you want using `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`. You can use that to set your `Content-Range`.

Comment: I'm already using ASIHTTPRequest and I'm moving away from it as it's no longer supported or developed. It suffers from the same problem though, setting the header is fine but the entire stream is sent as the request body which is not correct. I need to somehow seek the stream to the correct bytes offset and only send the remaining bytes.